# bernoullis inequality for $x \ge -2$ by induction

Tags: analysis, inequality

Prove the generalization of the bernoulli's inequality for $x \ge -2$.
I am aware of the proof for $x \ge -1$ .But I am unaware of the way to solve from -2 as x takes a negative value.

i am trying to prove the bernoullis inequality of (1+x)^n >= 1+nx for n belongs to N and x>=-2 using induction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define $q= 1+x$.
Let $-1>x \geq -2.$ (The other cases hold by normal proof.)
This implies $-1\leq q< 0$.
$q^r \geq q$ holds, since the $|q|^r\geq |q|$.
This means $q ^r \geq q =1+x \geq 1+rx$.